# Discriminator column in EF code first final release

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Stupid question: how do we specify the values of the discriminator column on EF 4.1 RTM? I've got this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>( )
            .Map<Individual>( m => m.Requires( ind => ind.EntityKind ).HasValue( 1 ) )
            .Map<Company>( m => m.Requires( c => c.EntityKind ).HasValue( 2 ) );
```

which follows the links I've found about it. However, it seems like HasValue doesn't take any parameters now. Any help on this? btw, where can I find the complete and correct docs about EF code first?

thanks.

Comment: Ado.Net Team blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>( )
            .Map<Individual>( m => m.Requires( "EntityKind").HasValue( "1" ) )
            .Map<Company>( m => m.Requires("EntityKind").HasValue( "2" ) );
```

Comment: thanks. btw, what's the idea? two overloads which return completely different things? I know overloading at the CLR level allows that, but in C#? really??? oh well...thanks again

Comment: btw, looks like class names got lost in copy & paste. You can also use .HasValue<int>(1), maybe the string version won't work if the "EntityKind" property type is not string.

Comment: no problem...I think that adding the generic type argument would be redundant, so it should work as is :)